# Multiple functions for mouse events jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm working on a jQuery plugin. To separate my logic I do something like this:

```
$element.on({
    mouseenter: function(){
      //do something special
    }, mouseleave: function(){
      //do something else special
    }
});
//more stuffs
```

and then above this I do that again but with other function body

```
$element.on({
    mouseenter: function(){
      //do something not special
    }, mouseleave: function(){
      //do something else not special
    }
});
```

How does jQuery deal with this ? Will 2nd declaration of mouse events function override the first one ? Sometimes I see both things works but sometimes not.

Comment: It will add both events.  Meaning you will have two `mouseenter` events fire and two `mouseleave`

Comment: is there any condition to execute first and second events. if not then you can combine both in one event handler.

Comment: So `do something special` and `do something not special` will execute simultaneous ?

Comment: @George02: Two different parts of your browser-based JavaScript code can **never** run simultaneously unless you use a [web worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/). There is only one main UI JavaScript thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will 2nd declaration of mouse events function override the first one ?

No.

> How does jQuery deal with this ?

It executes your event handlers in the order in which they were attached. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (about 40% down the page):

> Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound.

So for instance, if you have:

```
var div = $("#someDiv");
div.on("click", function() { console.log("one"); });
div.on("click", function() { console.log("two"); });
div.on("click", function() { console.log("three"); });
```

...then clicking the div will give you

```
one
two
three
```

...in the console.

Note that it doesn't matter how you found the element to attach the handlers. Let's say you have only one `div` on the page, it has the `id` `"someDiv"`, and it's the first child of `body` (just to make the selectors easy). If you have:

```
$("#someDiv").on("click", function() { console.log("one"); });
$(document.body).children().first().on("click", function() { console.log("two"); });
$("div").on("click", function() { console.log("three"); });
```

and you click the div, you'll get

```
one
two
three
```

...in the console.